# How to resize all div images to a particular size?

Tags: html, css

I have many image `divs` in a page. How do I resize all those images to a specific size (thumbnail size)? Currently all images shows their original big size. Is there a way to resize those `divs` images without changing the image tags inside those `divs`, preferably using CSS?

```
<div class="ItemLeft">


  <div class="Clipping">        
    <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/id8" title="galaxy">
      <img class="ItemImage" src="/Images/video8.jpg" alt="video 8" />
      <img class="OverlayIcon" src="/Images/1.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/id1234"><span class="Text">51:57</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="Title"><a href="/videos/id8" title="galaxy">galaxy</a></div>

  <div class="VideoAge">1 daybefore</div>

  <div class="PlaysInfo"> broadcast 265</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Now you can used to img width 100% http://jsfiddle.net/qdekP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply alter the css for either ImageLink or ItemImage classes in your CSS file.

Something Like This

```
.ImageLink{height: 100px; width: 50px}
.ItemImage{height: 100px; width: 50px}
```

This should set them all to the same height and width.

Comment: You could also use joeframbach's example if you want to apply the exact same CSS to both using less lines of code.

Comment: Many thanks all. dvide is there a way to show the overlayicon image in the middle of itemImage? How? <img class="OverlayIcon" src="/Images/1.png" alt="" />

Comment: @user1788736 Yes there is a way. you can set the z-index http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index which will essentially allow you to position something on top or below something else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ImageLink img {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is make the `img` tags span 100% of the `div`.

**CSS**

```
.Clipping {
  width: 300px; //your width
  height: 200px; //your height
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ImageItem {
  width: auto; //or 100%. Auto is to keep aspect ratio
  height: 100%;
}
```

This method is what I use on my websites because it is flexible for responsive design.  Instead of using a px value for the `div`, use percents for flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is, keep img tag common style (this will apply for all the images), you can set size for div or span. The image will adjust according to your div or span size.

```
img {max-width: 100%;height: auto;}
```